# Strings and || statements

Tags: java

Could you help me identify what I am missing with the code below?  I am using Eclipse.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    {
    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(("front door")  || ("front") || ("basement") || ("basement entrance")))
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(("front door")  || ("front"))        
            System.out.println("Maggie went to the side of the home and open the basement door.  As the door opened, she could smell the dust from inside.");       
        else    
            if ((input.equalsIgnoreCase("basement") || ("basement entrance")))  
                System.out.println("Maggie walks up the steps and slowly opens the front door.");               
    else    
        System.out.println("That is not a correct answer");
```

Comment: use `{}` with your ifs to be clear which if has which else..

Comment: The operands on either side of the || operator must have a boolean true/false value. They're not additional possibilties for an earlier function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a few errors:
1. If-else logic:

> a) if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(("front door")  || ("front") ||
>   ("basement") || ("basement entrance")))
>           if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(("front door")  || ("front"))

What do you mean here? Second if is redundant.
   b)

> else
>               if ((input.equalsIgnoreCase("basement") || ("basement entrance")))

this part is unreachable, because if covers it.

2. Syntax error in if(condition).

Suppose it should look llke

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
        {
            input = input.toLowerCase();

        if (input.equals("front door")  || input.equals("front"))             
                System.out.println("Maggie went to the side of the home and open the basement door.  As the door opened, she could smell the dust from inside.");       
        else if (input.equals("basement") || input.equals("basement entrance"))  
                    System.out.println("Maggie walks up the steps and slowly opens the front door.");               
        else    
            System.out.println("That is not a correct answer");
```

Comment: Put braces around the `if` bodies!

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use logical or operator, you have to do something like

```
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("front door") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("front") ||
    input.equalsIgnoreCase("basement") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("basement entrance")) {
    ...
}
```